# Printing lines in reverse order to a new file java

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program that reads each line in a file ("input.txt"), reverses it's lines and writes them to another file ("output.txt").

The input.txt file reads:

```
How much wood could a woodchuck chuck  
If a woodchuck could chuck wood?  
As much wood as a woodchuck could chuck,  
If a woodchuck could chuck wood.
```

and when the program is executed the output.txt file should read:

```
If a woodchuck could chuck wood. 
As much wood as a woodchuck could chuck,  
If a woodchuck could chuck wood?  
How much wood could a woodchuck chuck
```

The code I have so far is resulting only the first line printing to the output.txt file. I can't figure out how to get all 4 lines to print. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Everytime you close and re-open the file it starts to read from the start again. Read the whole file into an array instead in one go.

Comment: This is some confusing code, due partially to ignoring Java naming conventions. I don't understand why you're returning `lines.get(i)` inside a loop, which will stop executing the `FileReader` method immediately.

Comment: And this: `public static String String = null;` is just evil.

Comment: I'm new to java so I'm trying my best

Comment: @Fran_895 if you try to stick to the conventions of naming, indenting, etc, other developers will understand it much easier, therefore being able to help you.

Comment: @Jason Agree that conventional naming and formatting will ease support. Could you post an answer with guiding links to the `new to java` OP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reverse, just add the next line at the front. I have corrected your code (see below). See where I have added a comment

Also, the way you are doing this is bad practice (I don't know if this is boilerplate code you have to fill in). You honestly should define your function like

```
public static String ReadFile(String fileContents) throws...
```

or

```
public static String ReadFile (Reader r) throws ...{
}
```

Defining your method like this lets you first hardcode a test case in Java without worrying about the IO part. It also makes the method more useful as a Reader can come from a String reader, a Socket, or a file.

---

```
public static String ReadFile(String filePath) throws FileNotFoundException 
{

   File inputFile = new File (filePath);
   Scanner in = new Scanner (inputFile);
   String str = new String ("");
   while (in.hasNextLine())
   {
//       str += in.nextLine(); //this is wrong
       str = in.nextLine() + "\n" + str;
   }

   in.close();
   return str; // this is all the text in the file. thats the purpose of this methods 

}
```

Comment: You should use Java conventions such as methods starting with lower case, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
for (int i = lines.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    return(lines.get(i));
}
```

... doesn't do what you think it does.

The first time a return statement is executed, the method exits and returns only that value to the caller.

One way to approach your overall problem:

Your `FileReader(...)` method could return the `Array` object (unsorted because the method only infers that it will "read the file", then you could reverse the order of the array, then pass the reversed array to the `WriteFile(...)` method (or you could build a string from the reversed array and pass that).